# Prove each edge is part of a triangle in a random graph over a certain threshold - help

Tags: probability, graph-theory

[image]

Hello, I'm having some issues with proving this following problem. My guess would be to use a first moment method and proving the expectancy of a random variable which counts the amount of edges that aren't part of a triangle tends to zero as n approaches infinity. But I'm not too sure how to break this down so it works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strategy that will work.

First, for two fixed vertices $u$ and $v$, find the probability that they provide a counterexample to $\mathcal P$: that is, $uv \in E(G)$, but for every third vertex $w$, either $uw \notin E(G)$ or $vw \notin E(G)$. This probability can be computed exactly, though you'll later need to simplify it to an upper bound that's easier to work with.

Second, use linearity of expectation to find the *expected* number of pairs that provide a counterexample to $\mathcal P$.

Finally, if this goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, we can conclude that the probability that *any* pair will provide a counterexample also goes to $0$, and therefore $\mathcal P$ holds with high probability.

(Instead of linearity of expectation, we can phrase this in terms of using the union bound, if you prefer.)